# replace element with string in an array of integers in java

Tags: java, arrays, string, dynamic, integer

I'm trying to replace specific elements of an array of integers, based on some condition, with strings. I'm identifying the int elements which has to be replaced by using modulus operator.

```
class Source {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        int[] numbers = { 1, 2, 34, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15 };
        fizzBuzz(numbers);
    }

    public static void fizzBuzz(int[] numbers) {
        // Write the function body here
        for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
            if (numbers[i] % 3 == 0 && numbers[i] % 5 == 0) {
                numbers[i] = "FizzBuzz";
            } else if (numbers[i] % 5 == 0) {
                numbers[i] = "Buzz";
            } else if (numbers[i] % 3 == 0) {
                numbers[i] = "Fizz";
            } else {
                numbers[i] = numbers[i];
            }
            System.out.print(numbers[i] + " ");
        }
    }
}
```

I'm getting the error:

```
Source.java:11: error: inconvertible types
            numbers[i] = (int) "FizzBuzz";
                               ^
  required: int
  found:    String
Source.java:13: error: inconvertible types
            numbers[i] = (int) "Buzz";
                               ^
  required: int
  found:    String
Source.java:15: error: inconvertible types
            numbers[i] = (int) "Fizz";
                               ^
  required: int
  found:    String
3 errors
```

Comment: Why are you trying to do it that way? Why not just get the string based on the checks and print it?

Comment: You cannot store String in a int[] array.

Comment: Thanks all for the early responses @Maverick thanks for the information ChiefTwoPencils I'm a newbie and experimenting with the learning material

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm trying to `replace` specific elements of an array of `integers`, based on some condition, with `strings`.

In this particular case, the easiest way is to store the integers in the original array as `Objects`.  Then you just need to cast them to an `int` to work with them.

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    Object[] numbers = {1,2,34,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15};
    fizzBuzz(numbers);
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(numbers));
}

public static void fizzBuzz(Object[] numbers) {
    int i = 0;
    for (Object o : numbers) {
        int n = (int)o;
        boolean t3 = n % 3 == 0;
        boolean t5 = n % 5 == 0;

        numbers[i] = t3 && t5 ? "FizzBuzz" : t3 ? "Fizz" :
                t5 ? "Buzz" : n;
        i++;
    }
}
```

Prints

```
[1, 2, 34, Fizz, Buzz, Fizz, 7, 8, Fizz, Buzz, 11, Fizz, 13, 14, FizzBuzz]
```

Points to consider.

- establish the boolean results `once` and then simply apply them to a chained `ternary` operator. The ternary operator `a?b:c` means `if a is true then b, else c`
- since this uses `Objects` there is no issue of putting the result (either `String or int`) back into the array
- and since you are using only integers to begin with, you won't get a class cast exception when doing `(int)o`

Answer (score 3):

An array that was declared as an integer array cannot be filled with strings, as Java is a strongly typed language.

Here's how you can accomplish the same goal without violating Java's principles. You can print the result as soon as it is found based on the logic.

```
class Source {
  public static void main(String args[]) {
    int[] numbers = {1,2,34,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15};
    fizzBuzz(numbers);
  }

  public static void fizzBuzz(int[] numbers) {
      //Write the function body here 
      for(int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++){
          if(numbers[i] % 3 == 0 && numbers[i] % 5 == 0){
            System.out.print("FizzBuzz" + " ");
          }else if(numbers[i] % 5 == 0){
            System.out.print("Buzz" + " ");
          }else if(numbers[i] % 3 == 0){
            System.out.print("Fizz" + " ");
          }else {
            System.out.print(numbers[i] + " ");
          }
      }
  }
}
```